# What is the name of the theory that combines 3d discretized surfaces and distributed numerical algebra

Tags: numerics, parallel-computing, discretization, mesh, 3d

I've looked into distributed numerical computation work before, but I've realized that 3D applications are all about 3d surfaces and meshes.So I'd like to look into related work on mesh and parallel numerical computation

Comment: Can you elaborate what the question is? Are you interested in parallel 3d mesh *generation*?

Comment: Hello,, This is the first time I've heard of the concept of mesh generation, and I'm just starting out with the intention of being interested in the simulation of simulation engines and the rendering of meshes by computer graphics,...

Comment: Could  you please give me some guidance?QAQ

Comment: This is too broad a question. We cannot everything that has to do with parallel computations, meshes, and simulations here. You will need to narrow it down a bit.

Comment: I got it.Let me think about what my next most crucial thing is

Answer (score 2):

It's not specifically about parallel computation, but you might encounter some relevant research in the field of [isogeometric analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogeometric_analysis), i.e., the numerical solution of differential equations via finite element analysis on irregular domains represented by meshes and NURBS surfaces.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This would be a feasible direction, and I am trying to learn the theories related to parallel 3D mesh (computer graphics, mesh statistical analysis, etc.).